# Retrieving ID's from MYSQL-list rendered by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, mysqli

I'm currently using PHP and a MYSQL database to store and retrieve information regarding customers. The trouble I have, is that I'm rendering a list using PHP that displays all customers currently in the database, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT id, voornaam, achternaam FROM users ORDER BY id";
```

so that is going well and the page renders list from this query using the following code:

```
echo "<tr><td class='id_class'>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["voornaam"]. "</td><td>" . $row["achternaam"]. "</td><td>";
```

not a problem there. But the trouble is that I want to use a button with the Submit type to post an ID from a customer in this table, to another page. Using a counter does not work, as the button rendered is linked to the ID, which would be the last one loaded from the database.

So it is working for me, but every button always POSTs the last retrieved ID to the other page.

Question really is, how can I retrieve/store the IDs of every customer in the table, to use as a cross page variable?

I hope this explanation is thorough enough for you to see the trouble I'm in.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually it doesnt. We need to see how you are using the button... are you saying that the id is the button value? How is the row/id you want to post supposed to be selected? Or should it always be the same?

Comment: The creation of the button is very similar to what Marc B suggested in the answer below. My code is, due to it being some other language, is too confusing to post. But I too use a hidden input with the value set to the row ID, and then a submit input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a button per-row to do something with the record that row represents? QUick/dirty way is to embed a form per-row:

```
<tr>
   <td>blah blah blah</td>
   <td><form method="post" action="edit.php">
           <input type="hidden" name="recordID" value="$row[id]" />
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
       </form></td>
</tr>
```

That's kinda bulky, though. An easier method is to use some javascript/jquery to capture a click on a button in the form, and get the associated record ID:

```
<tr>
   <td>blah blah blah</td>
   <td><button onclick="editRecord(<?=$row[id]?>);"></td>
</tr>

function editRecord(id) {
    ... do something with the id
}
```

Comment: Well the 'dirty' way that you suggested is something that I've tried. But embedding a for per row still sets the ID of all the buttons to the last value retrieved from the database. I assume that is because you are referring to $row[id] which is changed everytime a new row is loaded from the database. Im gonna try the jquery way, thank you!

Comment: Then there must be a mistacke in your code somewhere because while **while you are in the loop** `$row['id']` is going to be the value for the current row/loop iteration.

Comment: So what you mean is that if I use '<td><form method="post" action="edit.php">
           <input type="hidden" name="recordID" value="$row[id]" />
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
       </form></td>', the Submit button will be created with the $row[id] that is currently loaded with that row, and will not change after that? - Sorry, really having trouble with the comment function of StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my own code, I'm very sorry. Guess that happens when you lose your overview. Thank you Marc B for providing the solution, and thanks to prodigitalson for pointing out that I was the error.

Have a nice day!